# Assignment of values to list elements in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
A=[x,y,z,x,z,x]
```

I want to assign 1 to all the occurrences of `x` in the list, 2 to all the occurrences of `y` and 3 to all the occurrences of `z`.
That is `x=1`, `y=2` and `z=3` for all occurrences of `x`, `y`, `z`.

What is the shortest way to do it?

Comment: are x, y, and z string literals 'x', 'y', 'z', or variable names?

Comment: Do you want to specify the mapping manually, or do you want to assign 1 to the first element seen and 2 to the next, and so on?

Comment: @icedtrees: Good question. OTOH, I guess if they are actual variable names you'd just do `x,y,z=1,2,3; A=[x,y,z,x,z,x]` :)

Comment: @PM2Ring I assumed they were variables that we didn't want to change

Comment: @AdamSmith: Ah! I didn't think of that. I guess we'll have to wait & see what Pushkar Dravid has to say...

Answer (score 5):

```
try:
    mapping = {x:1, y:2, z:3}
except TypeError:
    # either x, y, or z is unhashable
    new_A = [1 if el==x else
             2 if el==y else
             3 if el==z else 
             el for el in A]
else:
    new_A = [mapping[el] for el in A]
```

Comment: Assuming `x`, `y`, and `z` are hashable, of course.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams indeed! I'll write up a list comp in case `x`, `y`, or `z` aren't hashable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are asking

```
In [10]: A=["x","y","z","x","z","x"]
In [11]: d={"x":1, "y":2, "z":3}
In [12]: B=map(lambda x:d[x], A)
In [13]: B
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```

Comment: note that there's no need to make a lambda here. `B=map(d.get, A)` is equivalent.

Comment: Or `operator.getitem`.

Answer (score 0):

To compensate for the risk that you have something non-hashable, you could as well do

```
A = [x, y, z, x, z, x]
mapping = {id(x):1, id(y):2, id(z):3}
new_A_way1 = [mapping[id(el)] for el in A]
new_A_way2 = map(lambda el: mapping[id(el)], A)
```

As long as the objects are in existence, no other object can get their `id`, so this should be a safe way to go.